# How do I apply Bootstrap tooltip to ajax-loaded content?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I'm calling the following funciton on `ready()`. This predictably displays the Bootstrap tooltip for elements on my page that exist at `ready()` time, but not on ajax-loaded elements. I now am needing to have tooltips work on ajax-loaded content as well. How would I re-write this to allow new ajax-loaded elements to have the proper behavior?

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
  give_bootstrap_tooltip_behavior_to_all_elements_with_tooltip_attribute();
});

function give_bootstrap_tooltip_behavior_to_all_elements_with_tooltip_attribute() { 
  $( "[data-toggle='tooltip']" ).each(function(k,el){
    defaults = {
      delay: { show: 2000, hide: 0},
      container: 'body' /* needed because otherwise tooltips sometimes go within elems that have overflow hidden */
    }
    inline_vals = {
      delay: $(el).data('delay') 
    }
    $(el).tooltip($.extend(defaults, inline_vals));
  }); 
}
```

Would I have to call this in every ajax success method?

Answer (score 2):

you have to call when done ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '//url',
})
.done(function(data) {
    $('#page').html(data);
    give_bootstrap_tooltip_behavior_to_all_elements_with_tooltip_attribute();
})
...
```